# seeking example source code for GTK4 sourceview editor

Tags: linux, debian, c, gtk

To port [Bismon](https://github.com/bstarynk/bismon/) to GTK4, I need examples of working GTK4 source handling multi-font text, keypresses, etc.

This is for Linux/x96-64 only

And Bismon is GPLv3+ licensed (some kind of static source code analyzer)

Answer (score 1):

There is a Gedit alternative called Gnome-text-editor that is actively being developed (in C) that uses gtk4 / sourceview 5, that may be of interest to you, right here:

https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/gnome-text-editor

This is the author's blog / announcement, but if you search around you might also find some other useful resources/information;

https://blogs.gnome.org/chergert/2021/03/06/a-gtk-4-based-text-editor/

it should have examples of some functionality that you seek. However, I don't think it covers multi-font text (yet), or at least it didn't last year... But it's possible that has changed, as I haven't built/tested the app recently.

hope that helps.